# How to check through the whole user input and not just the first word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to check through user input but it only checks the first word. Any suggestions of how I can get the program to check through the whole string against a 2D list instead of just checking the first word and outputting missing.
Code below:

```
my_list = [['noisey','pc','broken']['smashed','window','glass']]
search = input('Enter what is going wrong: ')


notfound = 'True'

for i in mylist[0:1]:
   while notfound == 'True':
     if search in my_list[0]:
         print('Found in Pc')
         notfound = 'False'

     elif search in my_list[1]:
         print('Found in Home.')
         notfound = 'False'

     else:

          print('missing')
          notfound = 'False'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although each and everyone of us wishes to have superpowers of some sort, we do not have the power to read your code across the Internet. Please see [ask].

Comment: `$ man it – No manual entry for it` Sorry, not sure what "it" is…

Comment: sorry I will add it in now

Comment: I suppose your sublists in `my_list` split with a comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
my_list = [['noisey','pc','broken'],['smashed','window','glass']]
search = input('Enter what is going wrong: ')

for word in search.split():
    if word in my_list[0]:
        print(word,'Found in PC');
    elif word in my_list[1]:
        print(word,'Found in Home');
    else:
        print(word,"Not Found");
```

Output:

```
Enter what is going wrong: noisey pc smashed accidentally
noisey Found in PC
pc Found in PC
smashed Found in Home
accidentally Not Found
```